# Add command property to any custom controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I can navigate to another view with below Code. I want to use tabControl and Custom Controls for navigation but there is no Command property for binding myCommand.
so how can I bind my commands to custom controls?:

```
<Button Command="{Binding myCommand}" Content="Nav"/>
```

1.Is there anyway to bind?
2.how can I add command property to Custom controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### CustomControls and UserControls

Create `DependencyProperty` for command.

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(MyControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnCommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControl control = d as MyControl;
        if (control == null) return;

        control.MouseLeftButtonDown -= OnControlLeftClick;
        control.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnControlLeftClick;
    }

    private static void OnControlLeftClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControl control = sender as MyControl;
        if (control == null || control.Command == null) return;

        ICommand command = control.Command;

        if (command.CanExecute(null))
            command.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<local:MyControl Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
```

#### Other controls

Create attached behavior.

```
public static class ExecutesCommandOnLeftClickBehavior
{
    public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(ExecutesCommandOnLeftClickBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnCommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = d as UIElement;
        if (element == null) return;

        element.MouseLeftButtonDown -= OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
        element.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private static void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
        if (element == null) return;

        ICommand command = GetCommand(element);
        if (command == null) return;

        if (command.CanExecute(null))
            command.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid local:ExecutesCommandOnLeftClickBehavior.Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
```

You can change event to something other then `MouseLeftButtonDown`, add `DependencyProperty` (`AttachedProperty`) for CommandParameter if you need it.

Comment: @Ash: I'm familiar with InputBindings and I agree that a complete answer should include that. Aside that the question asked to _add CommandProperty_, I find it's more convenient to have a CommandProperty on my custom controls (we don't use InputBindings with Button though we could). Also consider that there might be reasons to execute the command, other than keyboard/mouse input.

Answer (score 5):

each UIElement has so called [`InputBindings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Input bindings support the binding of commands to input devices. For example, MouseBinding implements input bindings that include properties that are particular to mouse devices.

```
<Label Content="new">
    <Label.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" 
                      Command="{Binding Path=myCommand}" 
                      CommandParameter="smth"/>
    </Label.InputBindings>
</Label>
```

so instead of registering new Command and CommandParameter DP and handling events to trigger Command, try to use the functionality available out-of-box

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @djomlastic's answer in case anyone wants to send parameter with the command.

Create new dependency property,

```
public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CommandParameter), typeof(object)
                                                                               , typeof(<ClassName>), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

And send CommandParameter object as parameter instead of null when calling execute,

```
 private static void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
    if (element == null) return;

    ICommand command = GetCommand(element);
    if (command == null) return;

    if (command.CanExecute(element.CommandParameter))
        command.Execute(element.CommandParameter);
}
```