# Make an image act like a button in WPF

Tags: wpf, button

I have the below stackpanel that features 2 images. One of a tick and one of an exit.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal">

    <Image Source="C:\Users\USER\Pictures\Tick.png" Height="100" Margin="55,10,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Image Source="C:\Users\USER\Pictures\Exit.png" Height="88" Margin="75,10,20,5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

</StackPanel>
```

How am I able to make these 2 images act like a button? I know that you can use < button /> to create a new button, but I want to add a sort of property that will act as a button click when clicked.

Edit: I do not want the image to look like a button does with the outline and click effect. It just needs to be the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add command property to any custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849666/add-command-property-to-any-custom-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could completely customize the appearance of a button but still keep its functionality by creating a custom template:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Image Source="C:\Users\USER\Pictures\Tick.png" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

The above sample button should look exactly like an image but still be clickable like any other button.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give this a go now and drop an update after. Is this the simplest way this can be done?

Comment: @NiallUK: Yes, I think so. What could possible be simpler?

Comment: I was unsure if there was a simple click property i could add to my code that would create a new event handler.

Comment: @NiallUK: Did you see the `Click="Button_Click"` in my example? Or are you asking how to hook up an an event handler to a control in general?

Comment: @NiallUK: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make the image the Content of a Button?

```
    <Button Height="100" Margin="55,10,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="C:\Users\USER\Pictures\Tick.png"/>
    </Button>
```

Comment: I could do this. but i do not want the visual style that comes with a default button. I have edited my question.