# Using MVVM Community Toolkit, how to bind a UserControl Event to a RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, relaycommand, community-toolkit-mvvm

I try to customize WPF TextBox in order to raise event when the user made change in the user interface (but not on the programmatiques side so not using OnPropertieChanged). The objectif is also to extent this methodologie to other controls like NumericUpDown etc...

Here is my code :

```
<TextBox x:Class="WFP_vs_winform_control.validated.MyTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</TextBox>


    public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private bool userChange = false;    
        public event EventHandler UserMadeChange;  
        public MyTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            userChange = true;
            base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
        }
        protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (userChange) UserMadeChange?.Invoke(this, e);
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            userChange = false;
        }

<Window x:Class="WFP_vs_winform_control.validated.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WFP_vs_winform_control.validated"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test MyTextBox" Height="200" Width="350">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyTextBox Text="{Binding MyText,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" UserMadeChange="{Binding SaveCommand}" Margin="10" />
            <Label Content="{Binding MyText}"/>
            <Button Content="cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"  Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
    
</Window>

using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WFP_vs_winform_control.validated
{
    internal partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty] string myText = string.Empty;
        public ViewModel()
        {
        }

        [RelayCommand] private void Save()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Procedure to save data");
        }
        [RelayCommand] private void Cancel()
        {
            MyText = string.Empty ;
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is I can't do UserMadeChange="{Binding SaveCommand}", as it return Error XLS0523 Event 'UserMadeChange' can only be bound to properties of delegate type 'EventHandler'.

Can you help ?
Thanks in advance.

I try to find how Binding to RelayCommand work behind the scene, but did not find so much as the Community Toolkit not seams to be wildly use so far.

Comment: You can use InvokeCommandAction of XAML Behaviors for WPF https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki/InvokeCommandAction

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't really see how this can fix my problem ?

Comment: You can use UserMadeChange event to trigger InvokeCommandAction which is bound to RelayCommand.

Comment: What you mean by "but not on the programmatiques side so not using OnPropertieChanged" what change do you expect to happend without changing property? Could you please give more details about expected behaviour?

Comment: This is for machine interface, so the state (value) of my fields could be upgrade at any time by the machine, so PropertieChange is raised in that case. I only want to be notify when user make change on the interface ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks to emoacht I got something working. But it still not generic enough. How can I remove the Interaction trigger from the MainWindow to get it in the MyTextBox ?

```
<Window x:Class="WFP_vs_winform_control.validated.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WFP_vs_winform_control.validated"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Test MyTextBox" Height="200" Width="350">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyTextBox Text="{Binding MyText,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Margin="10">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="UserMadeChange">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </local:MyTextBox>
    <Label Content="{Binding MyText}"/>
    <Button Content="cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"  Margin="10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
    internal partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] string myText = string.Empty;
    public ViewModel() { }

    [RelayCommand] private void Save()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Procedure to save data");
    }
    [RelayCommand] private void Cancel()
    {
        MyText = string.Empty ;
        MessageBox.Show("Cancel");
    }
    public void SaveUserChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("save");
    }

}

<TextBox x:Class="WFP_vs_winform_control.validated.MyTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors">
```

```
    public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private bool userChange = false;    
    public event RoutedEventHandler UserMadeChange;
    //public ICommand UserChangeCommand { get; set; }


    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (userChange)
        {
            UserMadeChange?.Invoke(this, e);
            userChange = false;
        }
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Enter:
            case Key.Tab:
                if (userChange)
                {
                    userChange = false;
                    UserMadeChange?.Invoke(this, e);
                }
                return;
            case Key.Left: 
            case Key.Right:
            case Key.Up: 
            case Key.Down:
            case Key.PageUp:
            case Key.PageDown:
            case Key.Home: 
            case Key.End:
            case Key.LeftCtrl: 
            case Key.RightCtrl:
            case Key.LeftShift: 
            case Key.RightShift:
            case Key.CapsLock:
            case Key.LeftAlt: 
            case Key.RightAlt:
            case Key.LWin: 
            case Key.RWin:
            case Key.Apps:
            case Key.Escape:
                base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
                return;
            default:
                userChange = true;
                base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by _not generic enough_? If you want to make xaml simpler, adding Command to your MyTextBox is another choice.

Comment: Yes that is the question. How do I had a RelayCommand to my TextBox that is trigger by the event ?

Comment: You can add Command if you wish https://stackoverflow.com/q/47849666/3137337